# c# Copy SQL table data to another DB with Where clause filter using Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am in a process to copy data from one SQL database (Source) and move to another SQL Database (destination) through data factory using c# code.
I am able to copy all the data from a source table to destination table, but i want to move filtered data only, like SELECT * FROM Source.tbl WHERE Category = 5. There would be around 10-15 table that i would move data. Can you provide me sample code which may help me?

My code for moving single table all data..

// Authenticate and create a data factory management client
            var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantID);
            ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(AppID, AuthKey);
            AuthenticationResult result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", cc).Result;
            ServiceClientCredentials cred = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
            var client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(cred) { SubscriptionId = SubscriptionID };

```
        // Create data factory
        Factory dataFactory = new Factory { Location = Region, Identity = new FactoryIdentity() };

        // This line throws error, we cannot proceed further. unless we get access of creating DF or update or access.
        client.Factories.CreateOrUpdate(ResourceGroup, DataFactoryName, dataFactory);

        var DF = client.Factories.Get(ResourceGroup, DataFactoryName);

        while (DF.ProvisioningState == "PendingCreation")
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        LinkedServiceResource storageLinkedService = new LinkedServiceResource(
            new AzureSqlDatabaseLinkedService
            {
                ConnectionString = new SecureString(SourceSQLConnString)
            }
        );
        client.LinkedServices.CreateOrUpdate(ResourceGroup, DataFactoryName, SourceSQLLinkedServiceName, storageLinkedService);

        LinkedServiceResource sqlDbLinkedService = new LinkedServiceResource(
            new AzureSqlDatabaseLinkedService
            {
                ConnectionString = new SecureString(DestSQLConnString)
            }
        );
        client.LinkedServices.CreateOrUpdate(ResourceGroup, DataFactoryName, DestSQLLinkedServiceName, sqlDbLinkedService);

        DatasetResource SourceSQLDataSet = new DatasetResource(
            new AzureSqlTableDataset
            {
                LinkedServiceName = new LinkedServiceReference
                {
                    ReferenceName = SourceSQLLinkedServiceName
                },
                TableName = Table, 
            }
        );
        client.Datasets.CreateOrUpdate(ResourceGroup, DataFactoryName, SourceSQLDataSetName, SourceSQLDataSet);

        // Create a Azure SQL Database dataset
        DatasetResource DestSQLDataSet = new DatasetResource(
            new AzureSqlTableDataset
            {
                LinkedServiceName = new LinkedServiceReference
                {
                    ReferenceName = DestSQLLinkedServiceName
                },
                TableName = Table
            }
        );
        client.Datasets.CreateOrUpdate(ResourceGroup, DataFactoryName, DestSQLDataSetName, DestSQLDataSet);

        PipelineResource pipeline = new PipelineResource
        {
            Activities = new List<Activity>
            {
                new CopyActivity
                {
                    Name = "CopyFromSQLToSQL",
                    Inputs = new List<DatasetReference>
                    {
                        new DatasetReference()
                        {
                            ReferenceName = SourceSQLDataSetName
                        }
                    },
                    Outputs = new List<DatasetReference>
                    {
                        new DatasetReference
                        {
                            ReferenceName = DestSQLDataSetName
                        }
                    },
                    Source = new SqlSource(),
                    Sink = new SqlSink { }
                }
            }
        };
        client.Pipelines.CreateOrUpdate(ResourceGroup, DataFactoryName, PipelineName, pipeline);

        // Create a pipeline run
        CreateRunResponse runResponse = client.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(ResourceGroup, DataFactoryName, PipelineName).Result.Body;

        // Monitor the pipeline run
        PipelineRun pipelineRun;
        while (true)
        {
            pipelineRun = client.PipelineRuns.Get(ResourceGroup, DataFactoryName, runResponse.RunId);
            if (pipelineRun.Status == "InProgress")
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);
            else
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your query into the SqlReaderQuery property of your sql Source.

Comment: what about moving data for multiple tables?

Comment: Do you want to move data from multiple tables to a single table or to multiple table? If each source table corespons a sink table, you could use mulitiple copy activities, or you could use a for each activity which contains a copy activity.

Comment: it is multiple tables to multiple tables. Can you provide code example of mulitiple copy activities.

Comment: Will use a loop to add multiple activities in your pipeline work?

Comment: Most probably that would be the solution, i talked to the Data Factory support, they said we have not implemented yet, Create Data Factory, linked services, and in loop create datasets and copy activity.

Comment: Sorry. But I don’t understand why that need special implementation. And do you have to use c# to create the pipeline? Maybe you could use UI to generate the pipeline and check what the payload looks like? ADF provides copy data tool to help create pipelines copy data from multiple tables.

Comment: Doc for copy data tool. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-copy-data-tool

Answer (score 0):

I talked to the Data Factory support, they said we have not implemented yet, 
Create Data Factory, 
Create linked services
In loop create datasets and Create copy activity